# Stuck in a small confusion about Infrared leds and receivers?

Tags: arduino-uno, ir

I have a very simple idea I want to implement. I am making a home automation using an Arduino Uno. I am familiar with Arduino programming but the problem is what kind of IR receiver I need to buy if i want my TV remote (or similar) to communicate with my Arduino.

Can you suggest me any example (low cost, and available in India)?

Comment: Your title says "LED", but your body says "receiver".

Comment: Aren't they same

Comment: LEDs transmits IR light. Receivers receive the (modulated) IR light. You can get IR-receivers from old VCR etc.

Answer (score 1):

Element14 has an India based store, and they carry these IR devices. 
Here is one for 66 rupees:
http://in.element14.com/vishay-semiconductor/tsop38238/ir-receiver-45m-38khz-th/dp/2395954?MER=MER-BPR-4PPM-SP-VSHY-OD&

You may want to do research into what the carrier frequency of your remote is also. Most are generally around 35 - 40khz, and the receiver I provided a link to is 38khz. It should work, but if you want to be safe I suggest you look it up. Or, if you have an old TV lying around, you can pull one out of that.

Hope this helps.